# Issue with /etc/hosts and a local .dev domain

Tags: linux, macos, unix

My /etc/hosts contains this:

```
127.0.0.1 vanessa.dev
```

It's been working for weeks, but suddenly it no longer works. I can no longer get to it in a browser.

When I ping vanessa.dev on the command line I see:

```
~ $ ping vanessa.dev
PING vanessa.dev (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.179 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.186 ms
^C
--- vanessa.dev ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.052/0.139/0.186/0.062 ms
```

However, I can't curl, wget (http://)vanessa.dev, nor can I get there via the browser. Any troubleshooting tips?

Answer (score 3):

Are you getting "Connection Refused" (`ECONNREFUSED`) error messages?

Likely there's no server running there anymore.  Use `netstat` (on linux at least) to check:

```
sudo netstat -ltnp
```

or even

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep 80
```

If the latter is empty, or the former doesn't indicate anything listening on that port, your server is no longer running.

Answer (score 0):

Or use the "lsof" to find the process that run in 80 port :

> $ lsof -i:80

if there are no result , that means the HTTP server is not running .